# Unable to access typedef enum declared function in constant file in my viewController classes

Tags: ios, objective-c, enums

In `.pch` file I have created this `enum`:

```
typedef enum {
    PostTypeImage = 1,
    PostTypeVideo,
    PostTypeYoutubeVideo
}PostType;
```

Now I want to use this in my view controllers but I am unable to access them.

I am doing like this, in `.h` file I have created property for this
and in `.m` synthesized it but i am unable to achieve the desired result as  it show the error on this line itself

```
@property (strong, nonatomic)PostType postType;
```

Please help me in this,I know its a small thing but it really has taken a lot of my time

Comment: The property should be `assign` and not `strong`. Also, whenever you modify the `.pch` file make sure to Clean->Build the project.

Comment: `strong` is synonym for `retain` and should only be used for reference types (i.e. objects). Properties for value types (i.e. int, float, bool, CGRect, etc.) should be declared `assign` as @amar stated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A enumeration is a primitive C type, you don't need to retain it, use this:

```
@property (assign, nonatomic)PostType postType;
```

Same as if you were using an integer or a boolean.